# Keep printer settings when printing from command line

Tags: windows, printing

I am trying to print graphics from the command line. I am using the command rundll32 C:\Windows\System32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_PrintTo  , which works fine - BUT:

I have special settings for the desired printer. Those settings are set in the current settings and are used by default from all other programs. Only the above mentioned dll ignores my settings and kind of resets the printer (uses the factory settings).

Is there any way to prevent this?

Of course I could use another programm to print - but my solution has to run on as much (windows) pc's as possible, therefore I have to rely on build-in functions of windows.

Thanks for advice!